# How to manage the messages from the client to server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some clients that connect to the server at the same time, and each of them send to server a registration message.

So, the messages collide with previous messages when they come to the server.

How can I manage the communications without collision between the messages?

I use asynchronous tcp socket in C#.

Here the server:

```
class ServerSocket
{
    //The ClientInfo structure holds the required information about every
    //client connected to the server
    struct ClientInfo
    {
        public Socket socket;   //Socket of the client
        public string strName;  //Name by which the user logged into the chat room
    }

    //The collection of all clients logged into the room (an array of type ClientInfo)
    ArrayList clientList;

    //The main socket on which the server listens to the clients
    Socket serverSocket;

    byte[] byteData = new byte[5000];


    const int NUM_CLIENT = 12;

    public ServerSocket()
    {
        clientList = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void LoadServer()
    {
        try
        {
            //We are using TCP sockets
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,  ProtocolType.Tcp);

            //Assign the any IP of the machine and listen on port number 1000
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1000);

            //Bind and listen on the given address
            serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            serverSocket.Listen(NUM_CLIENT);

            //Accept the incoming clients
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);

            Console.WriteLine("###################### S E R V E R ######################");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);

            //Start listening for more clients
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);

            //Once the client connects then start receiving the commands from her
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), clientSocket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        string msgReceived = "";
        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

            msgReceived = GetString(byteData);

            string strTemp = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < msgReceived.IndexOf("<END>"); i++)
            {
                strTemp += msgReceived[i];
            }
            msgReceived = strTemp;

            XmlBaseClientMsg xmlBaseClientMsg = new XmlBaseClientMsg();
            BaseClientMsg baseClientMsgReceived = new BaseClientMsg();
            baseClientMsgReceived = xmlBaseClientMsg.DeserializeFromString(msgReceived);

            switch (baseClientMsgReceived.m_messageType)
            {
                case ClientMsgType.AI_REGISTRATION:

                    //When a user logs in to the server then we add him to our list of clients
                    ClientInfo AIClientInfo = new ClientInfo();
                    AIClientInfo.socket = clientSocket; // save the socket
                    AIClientInfo.strName = baseClientMsgReceived.m_sSenderID; // save the name of sender client

                    clientList.Add(AIClientInfo);

                    Console.WriteLine("The client: " + AIClientInfo.strName + " registered");
                    break;

                case ClientMsgType.ENTITY_REGISTRATION:

                    //When a user logs in to the server then we add him to our list of clients
                    ClientInfo EntityClientInfo = new ClientInfo();
                    EntityClientInfo.socket = clientSocket; // save the socket
                    EntityClientInfo.strName = baseClientMsgReceived.m_sSenderID; // save the name of sender client

                    clientList.Add(EntityClientInfo);

                    Console.WriteLine("The client: " + EntityClientInfo.strName + " registered");
                    break;
                #region
                //case Command.Logout:

                //    //When a user wants to log out of the server then we search for her 
                //    //in the list of clients and close the corresponding connection

                //    int nIndex = 0;
                //    foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                //    {
                //        if (client.socket == clientSocket)
                //        {
                //            clientList.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                //            break;
                //        }
                //        ++nIndex;
                //    }

                //    clientSocket.Close();

                //    break;
                #endregion

            }
            if (baseClientMsgReceived.m_messageType != ClientMsgType.AI_REGISTRATION)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type message: " + baseClientMsgReceived.m_messageType + " To: " +
                    baseClientMsgReceived.m_sReceiverID + " From: " + baseClientMsgReceived.m_sSenderID);

                foreach (ClientInfo clientInfo in clientList)
                {
                    if (clientInfo.strName == baseClientMsgReceived.m_sReceiverID)
                    {
                        byte[] message;
                        message = GetBytes(msgReceived);
                        // Send the message to reciever client
                        clientInfo.socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                            new AsyncCallback(OnSend), clientInfo.socket);

                        Console.WriteLine("Msg No : " + baseClientMsgReceived.m_nMessageID + " Type: " + baseClientMsgReceived.m_messageType + " ==> has been sent");
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }

            ////If the user disconnects so no need to listen to him
            // if (baseClientMsgReceived.m_messageType != ClientMsgType.Logout)
            //{

                //Start listening to the message send by the user
                clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), clientSocket);
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndSend(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
}


class Program
{
    public static int Main( String[] args ) 
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
        serverSocket.LoadServer();

        while(true)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use client identification, so you know who sent what and you have no collision?

Comment: Are you talking about threading because you've definitely got a threading problem around your access to the `clientList` array.